# PDF Metadata view using Pagination First, Next, Previous, Last

Tags: c#, pdf, view, pagination, metadata

I've created a class to read Metadata from a PDF file into a Textbox on a separate Form (InfoForm1)

```
    private void Info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PdfInformation info = pdfViewer1.Document.GetInformation();
        StringBuilder sz = new StringBuilder();

        sz.AppendLine($"Title:\t\t {info.Title}");
        sz.AppendLine($"Subject:\t\t {info.Subject}");
        sz.AppendLine($"Author:\t\t {info.Author}");

        InfoForm1_Link.Show();
        InfoForm1_Link.InfoText = sz.ToString();
    }
```

Now I'm trying to implement Pagination buttons (First, Next, Previous, Last) to view other files in a folder. So far I managed only to create these Methods.

I searched for answers regarding pagination system, however nothing relates to this case. Any idea how to proceed ? Thank You

```
        InfoForm1_Link.ButtonInfoFormClickedFirst += (s, eF) =>
        {
        };

        InfoForm1_Link.ButtonInfoFormClickedPrevious += (s, eP) =>
        {
        };

        InfoForm1_Link.ButtonInfoFormClickedNext += (s, eN) =>
        {
        };

        InfoForm1_Link.ButtonInfoFormClickedLast += (s, eL) =>
        {
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and trial & error, this works:

```
InfoForm1_Link.ButtonInfoFormClickedFirst += (s, eF) =>
{
    if (pFileNames.Length > 0)
    {
        i = 0;
        pdfViewer1.Document = OpenDocument(pFileNames[i]);
        txtInputFileT.Text = (pFileNames[i]);

        PdfInformation infoVar = pdfViewer1.Document.GetInformation();
        StringBuilder szVar = new StringBuilder();

        szVar.AppendLine($"Title:\t\t {info.Title}");
        szVar.AppendLine($"Subject:\t\t {info.Subject}");
        szVar.AppendLine($"Author:\t\t {info.Author}");

        InfoForm1_Link.InfoText = szVar.ToString();
    }
};
```